# Can I disable specific pylint warnings for a single project?

Tags: python, emacs, configuration-files, pylint

I know you can disable specific pylint warnings globally, by editing `~/.pylintrc`, or locally, by adding `# pylint: disable=(...)` to a particular code block.

I'm writing a library, and I would like to disable certain warnings for all files in the project. Ideally I'd put this list of disabled warnings in some pylintrc file that I place at the project's root directory. I want this to apply only when I'm pylinting source files from that directory and below.

Is there a way to do this?

I use pylint purely through its emacs interface, epylint.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly no. You can have a pylintrc file for a project but not for a package only.

Comment: Actually, having a pylintrc for a single project (not package) would be completely fine for my purposes. I've edited the question to clarify this. Could you tell me how to set a pylintrc file for a single project? When running pylint from within emacs (M-x pylint), how would it find this pylintrc file?